# How to silently provide initial settings for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, settings, visual-studio-2017

I'm looking for a way to provide initial settings for Visual Studio 2017 through a script. Copying a `*.vssettings` file to the `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Settings` path doesn't work since Visual Studio will rewrite the file on startup while creating a user profile.

There is the [/resetsetting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx) switch vor `devenv.exe` which can be used to reset the settings to a specified `.vssettings` file, but this will also open Visual Studio IDE.

Is there a way to silently provide initial settings for Visual Studio from a PowerShell script? Or any safe way to detect at which time Visual Studio has created the profile and imported the settings when using `/resetsetting`, so that the `devenv` process can be killed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `/resetsettings`, you could:

1. Check whether default settings file exists. Get modified date if it does.
2. Run `devenv.exe /resetsettings <filepath>` The modified date on the default settings file will be changed to match the file specified.
3. Check modified date has changed, or file now exists.
4. Close `devenv.exe`

I've given this a go; the settings file after step 3 isn't identical to the one specified in `/resetsettings`, although it's clearly different from the previous default one. I don't know the criteria for which tags are kept.

**Related, not a PowerShell solution:** [A team settings file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/xdfb57tf(v=vs.90).aspx) can be specified by going to Tools > Options > Environment > Import and Export Settings. More info on [Enviornment Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/environment-options-dialog-box).

**Note from link:** *"When applied, these team settings would not override any category not specified in the .vssettings file"*